# How to calculate this limit

Tags: calculus

I need find the follow limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1^{\pi}+2^{\pi}+\cdots+n^{\pi}}$. Please help me. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will use the property: *If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a, \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=a$, then a sequence $(c_n)$ at property $a_n\leq c_n \leq b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a convergent and $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=a$.*

Since

$$
1\leq \sqrt[n]{1^{\pi}+2^{\pi}+\cdots+n^{\pi}}<\sqrt[n]{n^4+n^4+\cdots+n^4}=\sqrt[n]{n\cdot n^4}=\left(\sqrt[n]{n}\right)^5.
$$

Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[n]{n}\right)^5=1$ by the above property, we have:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1^{\pi}+2^{\pi}+\cdots+n^{\pi}}
$$

Answer (score 3):

use 
$$1<1^{\pi}+2^{\pi}+\cdots+n^{\pi}<n\cdot n^{\pi}$$
so
$$1<\left(1^{\pi}+2^{\pi}+\cdots+n^{\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}<n^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot (n^{\pi})^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

and note 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1,$$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1^{\pi}+2^{\pi}+\cdots+n^{\pi}}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sqrt[n]n\le\sqrt[n]{1^\pi+\ldots +n^\pi}\le\sqrt[n]{n^{\pi+1}}$$